# SQL Server 2005 replication of DBs cross-server -- need to know when a row was inserted/updated on the target server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, business-intelligence, database-replication

I am BI Manager on top of a SAP installation. I have a SAP DB which the SAP application writes data to. In order to get an environment to query without loading on the sap, I have mirrored the SAP DB on a server, and it works fine.

Each night I do a full load of data, and it works fine for now. I know that somewhere down the line, I will have to start doing incremental updates.

This will be a lot easier if I know which rows in the tables have been modified or added, and when. Is it possible to make a trigger on the target server that writes into the table when it was updated or created? A lot of the time, there is no indication of the date the row was created in the source tables. I am not well acquainted with the rules of mirroring and replication

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to fix this is probably to update your table to add a `timestamp` column, and have it default to the current versioing item. You can look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776%28SQL.90%29.aspx) for more information, but the format is basically the following...

```
ALTER TABLE <tablename> ADD timestamp
```

As noted in that link, you do not need to specify a column name, as it will automatically start tracking the timestamp during inserts/updates.

Note that this solution does not give you a human readable time - the item given is unique to the  (just something that is easy for versioning). If you want a time, you can make a `DATETIME` column that defaults to `GETDATE()` (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258905%28SQL.80%29.aspx) for more info). When you insert/update a row, you would just ignore inserting/updating anything in that particular column, and the current `DATETIME` would be added for you.

Comment: Okay, I was thinking in those lines, just was'nt sure that it would work on the target server in a replication chain?

Comment: I've not done it in a set-up like that, however, if you're adding everything to the target server, the timestamps should all be consistent. Replication should strictly copy the table (see here [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx]), not reinsert the rows into a new table on the replication chain. Thus, the timestamps shouldn't be changed.

Comment: +1 but it doesn't make sense to say "add a timestamp column, and have it default to the current time." It has no time element to it.

Comment: Edited - alas, `timestamp` was a poor choice of syntax naming regarding this, as it is misleading. Hopefully my clarification helps, but I suspect the `timestamp` bit will continue to throw people off.

Comment: That's why we're supposed to use the ROWVERSION synonym now.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx